# Call Microsoft Graph API to get user in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have an android application that uses Azure AD B2C. Users can sign up using local account/email. Once the user logs into the android application, I'm trying to call the Microsoft Graph API to get the signed-in users details (specifically the Graph API UPN of the user, which is different than the UPN in Azure ad B2C).

The API call I'm trying to make is: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
I added the bearer auth token I receive when the user logs in.

However, I receive the following error:

```
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-17T06:11:32",
      "request-id": "b4e9757e-60d9-453f-820d-9f817831aa0c"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what I can do to get the user's Graph API UPN? Appreciate the help!

Comment: What endpoint did you use to obtain the access token? Can you try to call this API using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer (this requires you to log in)?

Comment: @CarlZhao i used my B2C endpoint (SignUpSignIn flow) to get the auth token. Should I using some other endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when the token used is invalid. If you want to get the logged-in user information, you can request the API at [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

[image]

Don't forget to grant administrator consent for this permission,please check[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

**Update**

For Azure b2c users, it is currently not possible to call the Graph API.https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526

Comment: my user is a b2c user. I tried logging in with a test user in graph explorer but the login did not succeed. Any idea how I can use a B2C login to get the information pertaining to that user? Also, does each B2C user need to be granted admin consent to use the graph api? My App (Client ID) already has the necessary admin consent

Comment: @DataGeek For Azure b2c users, unfortunately, it is currently not possible to call the Graph API, so you cannot get the information of the logged-in user by calling this API.https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, @CarlZhao